# IE doesn't align text and image properly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

In Chrome image and the text link is aligned properly. However, when I check it on IE8, I noticed that image and text link is not align properly.

Here is the code I use. this is a code I use in Wordpress wpfilebase templates.

```
<td style="width:350px;padding-left:20px;">
    <a href="%file_url%"> 
       <img align="top" src="%file_icon_url%" alt="%file_display_name%" height="40" />
    </a>
    <span style="width:200px;float:right;vertical-align:text-top;">
    <a href="%file_url%"> %file_display_name%</span></a>
</td>
```

[image: IE view]

[image: Chrome view]

Chrome renders properly, but not IE. How to fix this? If I need to use conditional CSS for IE, what is the correct code for IE?

Comment: You change the IE version and check your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'span' tag closes before you close your 'a' tag. Corrected Code:

```
 <td style="width:350px;padding-left:20px;">
   <a href="%file_url%"> 
     <img align="top" src="%file_icon_url%" alt="%file_display_name%" height="40" />
   </a>
   <span style="width:200px;float:right;vertical-align:text-top;"> 
     <a href="%file_url%">%file_display_name%</a>
  </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Also, another thing with IE is the use of spans. I would also try moving the span before the < a> tag.

Comment: Does IE8 have problems with span element?

Comment: I have seen it happen with IE7.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<td style="width:350px;padding-left:20px;" valign="top"><!--use valign top here -->
    <a href="%file_url%"> 
     <img align="top" src="%file_icon_url%" alt="%file_display_name%" height="40" alt="img" />
    </a>
    <span style="width:200px;padding-left:10px;vertical-align:text-top;"> <!--remove float and add padding here-->
     <a href="%file_url%">%file_display_name%</a><!--anchor tag should be closed here-->
    </span>
</td>
```

Use `padding-left` in **span element** and remove `float property` from it.

Comment: But when the text name is longer one then rest of the text goes under the image

Comment: then use `min-width:200px` instead of `width:200px` in `span element`

Comment: why do you to define alt two times?

Comment: `Use padding-left in span element and remove float property from it.` could you please explain the reson to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Using div tag instead of span, solved my issue.

```
<td style="width:350px;padding-left:20px;" valign="top"><!--use valign top here -->
    <div style="float:left;"><a href="%file_url%"> 
     <img align="top" src="%file_icon_url%" alt="%file_display_name%" height="40" alt="img" />
    </a></div>
    <div style="max-width:200px;padding-left:10px;vertical-align:text-top;"> <!--remove float and add padding here-->
     <a href="%file_url%">%file_display_name%</a><!--anchor tag should be closed here-->
    </div>
</td>
```